# Unable to launch jnlp with Adopt JRE

Tags: java, jnlp, icedtea

Scenario 1: 
With Oracle JDK - jdk1.8.0_221, jnlp was launching seamlessly without any issues.

Scenario 2: 
Removed any previous java env variables(jdk1.8.0_221) and tried to run the same jnlp with, adoptopenjdk (OpenJDK8U-jre_x64_windows_hotspot_8u242b08) along with Iceicedtea-web-1.8.3, but facing below issue.

```
C:\Users\goh\Downloads\check_java>my_goh.bat
selected jre: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221
thread 'main' panicked at 'Error spawning JVM process, java executable: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221], arguments: [["-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:C:\\Users\\goh\\Downloads\\check_java\\log4j2.xml", "-splash:C:\\Users\\goh\\Downloads\\check_java\\adoptjava8\\icedtea-web-image\\share/icedtea-web\\javaws_splash.png", "-Xbootclasspath/a:C:\\Users\\goh\\Downloads\\check_java\\adoptjava8\\icedtea-web-image\\share/icedtea-web\\javaws.jar;C:\\Users\\goh\\Downloads\\check_java\\adoptjava8\\icedtea-web-image\\share/icedtea-web\\plugin.jar;C:\\Users\\goh\\Downloads\\check_java\\adoptjava8\\icedtea-web-image\\share/icedtea-web\\jsobject.jar;C:\\Users\\goh\\Downloads\\check_java\\adoptjava8\\icedtea-web-image\\win-deps-runtime\\js.jar;C:\\Users\\goh\\Downloads\\check_java\\adoptjava8\\icedtea-web-image\\win-deps-runtime\\tagsoup.jar;C:\\Users\\goh\\Downloads\\check_java\\adoptjava8\\icedtea-web-image\\win-deps-runtime\\mslinks.jar;C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_221\\lib\\ext\\nashorn.jar;", "-classpath", "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_221\\lib\\rt.jar;C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_221\\lib\\ext\\jfxrt.jar;", "-Dicedtea-web.bin.name=javaws.exe", "-Dicedtea-web.bin.location=C:\\Users\\goh\\Downloads\\check_java\\adoptjava8\\icedtea-web-image\\bin\\javaws.exe", "net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot", "http://<myapp>:8080/<applet>/launchClient"]]', src\os_access.rs:42:19
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
```

Unsure why its referring back to "java executable: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221]", eventhough the bat file has - C:\Users\goh\Downloads\check_java\adoptjava8\icedtea-web-image\bin\javaws.exe

I have extracted & placed - icedtea-web-1.8.3.win.bin inside  OpenJDK8U-jre_x64 folder.

**my_goh.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET _param=%~1
SET _token=!_param:; =;%%20!
"C:\Users\goh\Downloads\check_java\adoptjava8\icedtea-web-image\bin\javaws.exe" -J-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:"C:\Users\goh\Downloads\check_java\log4j2.xml" http://<myapp>:8080/<applet>/launchClient
```

Requirement is launch my application from the bat file which specified the java & javaws location.

OS: WIndows 10 & Windows 2012 server

Comment: Do you have a JAVA_HOME Variable set? Is the 8u221 physically uninstalled from the system or does it still exists? Also check the following folder: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath